# Custom block from module

Tags: blocks, 8

I am trying to create a custom block using a module.

I have followed the instructions on the Drupal site but my block does not appear in the list of custom blocks, or at the bottom of the Block Layout page.

So I installed the Examples for Developers module. It seemed to install and enable correctly but again, there didn't seem to be any example blocks in the Structure, Blocks Layout screen.

Thinking that there must be something wrong with my installation, I used the demon site to test the example modules: https://simplytest.me/project/examples/8.x-1.x

Again, when I enable the Block Example module I don't see any block modules in the list of custom blocks, or at the bottom of the Block Layout page.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this broken in Drupal 8.0?

Comment: I don't know if you have access to any error logs in simplytest.me. Usually if the block does not appear in the block interface there is some php error, which is ignored by the ui.

Comment: I'll check it. But the error must be in Core, or at least the Example Module.

Comment: Did you click place block?

Comment: larowlan - now I feel like an idiot. That was the problem. I was expecting to the the blocks listed either in the custom blocks section or in the list of unplaced blocks below the placed ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add a new block you need to click on the button place block then click again on the place block button base on what block you want to added it.

[image: Example of the Block Layout]